# Kend0, legend of chart, title and scroll

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Exist any possibility to add title to kendo legend (of chart) ?

My current legend looks:

- item 1
- item 2

I want to have:

LEGEND
- item 1
- item 2

Exist possibility to add scroll bar to kendo legend ?
(for example, height fixed to 200 px and when exist a lot of legend item - scroll bar)

Answer (score 0):

**Scrollbar in a legend** :

It is *possible* but it is a lot of work. The legend is inside the SVG or Canvas, depending on your drawing mode. Scrollbars aren't really a thing in those environments. The easier approach is to write a custom widget of your own that is a legend in plain HTML. From the data in the Chart widget, you can get the list of legend items and their colors.

I had to implement this in Telerik Analytics, and it took a day or 2 to get right, but worked out in the end. Unfortunately, the code is proprietary so I can't share it here.